# Inheritance in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the next code with inheritance.

```
function FileS(){}
FileS.prototype.getS = function (num){
    console.log(num);
}
FileS.prototype.getDynamic = function(){
 // WHAT I need to write here, so the function would call the DYNAMIC function
}

S3.prototype= new Files();
S3.prototype.constructor = S3();
function S3(){}
S3.prototype.getS = function (num){
     console.log("This is for S3: " + num);
}

function dataE(u){
   var s3 = new S3();
   s3.getDynamic();
}
```

As I understand, `s3` will call to `FileS.protortpe.getDynamic`, because it hasn't this function in `S3` prototype. But now, I want that `FileS.protortpe.getDynamic`  will call to `s3.protortpe.getS`, if the type is `S3`, and `FileS.prototype.getS` otherwise. How can I do it (without specify `s3` or `FileS`, because that is more types..)?

Comment: This isn't right `S3.prototype.constructor = S3();`. You want to assign a reference to the function, not an instance or return value.

Comment: And using `new Files` to create `S3`'s prototype is an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the correct way to set up a prototype hierarchy using constructor functions:

```
// ==== FileS ====
function FileS() {
}
// Add any FileS prototype things to `FileS.prototype`

// ==== S3 ====
function S3() {
    FileS.call(this); // You could pass args here if appropriate
}
S3.prototype = Object.create(FileS.prototype);
S3.prototype.constructor = S3; // Optional, but a good idea
// Add any S3 prototype things to `S3.prototype`
```

...where we shim the single-argument version of `Object.create` if necessary for older browsers, like this:

```
if (!Object.create) {
    Object.create = function(proto, props) {
        if (typeof props !== "undefined") {
            throw "The multiple-argument version of Object.create cannot be shimmed.";
        }
        function ctor() { }
        ctor.prototype = proto;
        return new ctor();
    };
}
```

---

Because that's a fair bit of boilerplate, <s>I have a [small helper script called `Lineage`](http://code.google.com/p/lineagejs/) to do it for me.</s> these days I use ES2015's `class` syntax and a transpiler like [Babel](http://babeljs.io).

Comment: But how the call to GerS is changed according to specific type? If the type S3, it should go to the function of S3, and Otherwise to FileS. And this I know just when I run my program.

Comment: @OrSmith: Where I've said "Add any XX prototype things to `XX.prototype`" above, that's where you'd put the `getS` function for each type. An object created with `new S3` will get S3's version; an object created with `new FileS` will get FileS's version.