# ES6 calling super() doesn't properly initialize parent class

Tags: javascript, inheritance, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have the following code structure, I try to initialize parent class by calling super(), but when i call this._init() it calls the one of the child. any help how can I fix this?

```
class Parent {
    constructor() {
    console.log('P constructor()');
    this._init();
  }

  _init() {
    console.log('P _init()');
    this.parentProp = 'parent';
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    constructor() {
    console.log('C constructor');
    super();
    this._init();
  }

  _init() {
      console.log('C _init()');
    this.childProp = 'child';
  }

  test() {
    console.log(this.childProp + ' ' + this.parentProp);
  }
}

let child = new Child();
child.test();
```

Here's the output of the above code:

```
C constructor()
P constructor()
C _init()
C _init()
child undefined
```

Comment: You cannot. You overwrote the method, so the initial method is not available anymore.

Comment: I have nothing to do but calling super._init() which i consider not a good practice because this belongs to the parent class.

Comment: "which i consider not a good practice" --- your consideration is not aligned with the common practices. There is nothing wrong in calling a base method from the child one.

Comment: _"calling super._init() which i consider not a good practice"_ Neither is calling `this._init()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Child#_init` is getting called because that's what the `_init` property on the object refers to when `this._init()` (in `Parent`) is called. What happens (leaving out some details) is:

1. `new` creates a new object whose `[[Prototype]]` is `Child.prototype`. `Child.prototype`'s `[[Prototype]]` is `Parent.prototype`.
2. `new` calls `Child`.
3. `Child` calls `Parent`.
4. `this._init()` looks up the `_init` property on the object. Since the object doesn't have its own `_init` property, the JavaScript engine looks to its `[[Prototype]]`. `Child.prototype` *does* have an `_init` property, so the engine uses that one.

As for solving it: JavaScript classes have only one constructor, so there's no real purpose to having a separate `_init` function.<sup>1</sup> That's what constructors are for. Despite their name, they don't construct objects, they *initialize* them. So just put `_init`'s code in the constructor itself:

```js
class Parent {
  constructor() {
    console.log('P constructor');
    this.parentProp = 'parent';
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  constructor() {
    console.log('C constructor');
    super();
    this.childProp = 'child';
  }

  test() {
    console.log(this.childProp + ' ' + this.parentProp);
  }
}

let child = new Child();
child.test();
```

Alternately, just remove the `this._init()` call from `Child` entirely and have `Child#_init` call `super._init()`. I know you've said in a comment you think that's poor practice (it isn't, it's standard practice), but if you want to break out `_init` to separate functions, that's what you do. But doing so violates the principal, well-established cross-language, that calling overrideable methods from a constructor (`Parent` calling `this._init()`) is a Bad Idea™. :-)

If you absolutely insist on separating the code out into a function, and don't want to use `super._init()` in `Child#_init`, it'll need to be separate from the class:

```js
let Parent = (function() {
  class Parent {
    constructor() {
      console.log('P constructor');
      initParent.call(this);
    }
  }

  function initParent() {
    console.log("initParent");
    this.parentProp = 'parent';
  }

  return Parent;
})();

let Child = (function() {
  class Child extends Parent {
    constructor() {
      console.log('C constructor');
      super();
      initChild.call(this);
    }

    test() {
      console.log(this.childProp + ' ' + this.parentProp);
    }
  }

  function initChild() {
    console.log("initChild");
    this.childProp = 'child';
  }

  return Child;

})();

let child = new Child();
child.test();
```

---

<sup>1</sup> I could see using a method in a language with overloaded constructors — although even there I advocate having them call each other rather than a utility method — but not in JavaScript.

Comment: "Despite their name, they don't construct objects" --- what the "constructor" is supposed to do if not initialise an object then?

Comment: @zerkms Only `new` and `super()` really create the object, the job of the `.constructor` method is to initialise that instance.

Comment: @zerkms: I'm not sure I understand your question. The quote from the answer is *"Despite their name, they don't construct objects, they **initialize** them."*.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I just tried to be snarky, that "constructor" and "initialiser" are indistinguishable processes and likely to not even have the single "official" definition :-)

Comment: @Bergi or - `new` really allocates memory for the object and `.constructor` constructs the instance :-)

Comment: @zerkms Yeah, "initialiser" probably would've been the better term. If you invoke `child.constructor()`, you don't (re-)construct an instance, you re-initialise it.

Comment: @zerkms: `new` does more than memory allocation. Aside from bookkeeping details like ensuring the function is actually a constructor and setting the new target (important for proper subclassing), the two really major things it does are allocate memory and assign the object's prototype. (And I don't think "construction" and "initialization" are indistinguishable at all, nor do I think that's a common view.)

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder Zerkms and Bergi, that was really useful!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder how to make it with ES5?

Comment: @Roar: Make what, a basic inheritance hierarchy? If so: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23468022/157247

Comment: @T.J.Crowder https://jsbin.com/bafuroraxu/edit?js,console,output make Tiger constructor pass name to Mammol constructor and init field

Comment: @Roar: Sounds like you need to post an actual question, but only after doing a thorough search. Note that that bin doesn't have at least one of the essential parts from my link above.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is not to use an `init` method at all. A constructor should not call overwritable methods:

```
class Parent {
  constructor() {
    console.log('P constructor()');
    this.parentProp = 'parent';
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  constructor() {
    console.log('C constructor');
    super();
    this.childProp = 'child';
  }
  test() {
    console.log(this.childProp + ' ' + this.parentProp);
  }
}

let child = new Child();
child.test();
```

Alternatively, in your case it would have worked to call the super method in `_init` and not to call `_init` from the Child constructor:

```
class Child extends Parent {
  constructor() {
    console.log('C constructor');
    super();
  }
  _init() {
    super._init();
    console.log('C _init()');
    this.childProp = 'child';
  }
  …
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Actually the `Parent` `constructor` should be able to call it without trouble, so the OPs code would work if he changed `Child` to what I suggested. Of course, this is a bad solution with inverted control. And calling overridable methods before the constructor has finished generally is asking for trouble (it only does not matter here because the Child constructor doesn't do anything)

Comment: Yes, quite so, I suppose the root can do it. Although as you've said, it's a well-known anti-pattern to call overrideable methods from a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Basically here in our case `super()` is equals to `Parent.call(this)`, Where `this` would points to `Child`. So `Child.prototype._init` will be called twice and that property `parentProp` will not be created.

And this is the reason why, you are seeing the following console outputs.

```
C constructor()
P constructor()
C _init() //printed from Child.prototype._init
C _init() //printed from Child.prototype._init
child undefined
```