# ES6: Super class doesn't hold state

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class, es6-modules

I'm trying to figure out what's going on here, as the Parent/Super class does not have data after the initial construction.

// imports/server/a-and-b.js

```
class A {
  constructor(id) {
    // make MongoDB call and store inside this variable
    // ...
    this._LocalVariable = FieldFromMongo;
    console.log(`this._LocalVariable: ${this._LocalVariable}`); // => This has a good value, ie: 'Test'
  }
  get LocalVar() {
    console.log(`this._LocalVariable: ${this._LocalVariable}`); // => This has a undefined value when called from child class
    return this._LocalVariable;
  }
}

export class B extends A {
  constructor(id) {
    super(id);
    this.TEST = 'THIS IS A TEST';
  }
  get THE_Variable() {
    console.log(`super.LocalVar: ${super.LocalVar}`); // => This has a undefined value when called
    return super.LocalVar;
  }
  get GETTHEVAR() {
    return this.TEST; // => This returns 'THIS IS A TEST'
  }
}
```

// imports/server/factory.js

```
import { B } from 'imports/server/a-and-b.js';

class Factory {
  constructor() {
    this._factory = new Map();
  }
  BuildInstances(id, cls) {
    let instance = this._factory.get(cls);

    if (!instance) {
      if (cls === 'B') {
        instance = new B(id);
        this._factory.set(cls, instance);
        return instance;
      }
    }
    else {
      return instance;
    }
  }
}
export let OptsFactory = new Factory();
```

// imports/server/test.js

```
import { OptsFactory } from 'imports/server/factory.js'

const B = OptsFactory.BuildInstances(id, 'B');

const THE_Variable = B.THE_Variable; // => always undefined

const TEST = B.GETTHEVAR; // => Always returns 'THIS IS A TEST'
```

Why does class A not keeping state?

Comment: Sounds like your MongoDB call is asynchronous and you're expecting to get a synchronous value. Could you provide some sample code showing how you're getting that value from the database?

Comment: The value actually comes back from Mongo, I see it in the console.log, in the code above, it's this line:   console.log(`this._LocalVariable: ${this._LocalVariable}`); // => This has a good value, ie: 'Test'.  It's only when I call it from the Child class that it's undefined -- like it never set its own state or like the Child class doesn't keep the proper reference?

Comment: Really hard to follow this problem, particular with the use of pseudo-code like names and no actual real functionality.  You don't access instance data with `super.XXX`.  You use `this.XXX`.  There's only one object, one `this` pointer and all parts of the class (base and derived classes) all access the same object and the same `this` pointer.  So, `this.XXX` accesses a property no matter which part of base or derived class created it or set it.

Comment: Are you using a transpiler? `super` access to getters might have some bugs.

Comment: Given you are using different property names anyway, try `this.LocalVar` instead of `super.LocalVar`.

Comment: @jfriend00 You can use `super` when you are overwriting a getter or getter. But yeah, it normally shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I found:

```
class A {
  constructor(id) {
    // make MongoDB call and store inside this variable
    // ...
    this._LocalVariable = FieldFromMongo;
  }
  get LocalVar() {
    return this._LocalVariable;
  }
  GetThatLocalVar() {
    return this._LocalVariable;
  }
}

export class B extends A {
  constructor(id) {
    super(id);
  }
  get Style1() {
    // Reference to Parent get function
    return super.LocalVar; // => This has a undefined value when called
  }
  get Style2() {
    // Reference to Parent property
    return super._LocalVariable; // => This has a undefined value when called
  }
  get Style3() {
    // Reference to local Property that is declared in Parent
    return this._LocalVariable; // => This works
  }
  get Style4() {
    // Reference to Parent without the getter
    return super.GetThatLocalVar(); // => This works
  }
  get GETTHEVAR() {
    return this.TEST; // => This returns 'THIS IS A TEST'
  }
}
```

So basically the thing that works is Style3 Style 4 work.

Comment: You access instance data with `this.xxx`, not with `super.xxx`.  There's only one object and one `this` that all parts of the class use, whether the functionality is in the base class or in a derived class.

Comment: Yes, even if the Parent initializes the property is seems.

Comment: It doesn't matter how the property is set.  There's only one object and thus only one `this`.  It can be set from base class, from derived class or from outside the object via object reference.  It's all just one object.  People seem to like to think that each class initializes it's own separate object when instantiated, but that is not the case.  It's just one object.

Comment: Do you have any reference materials?  I couldn't find any details on this online.  Even a video course is fine, I just need to understand the underlying details as you do.

Comment: I just know how it works internally from programming in JS for awhile, not sure of reference materials.  Read any ES6 guide and you won't find `super.xxx` to reference an `xxx` property on an instance.

Comment: No, I looked at it all MDN, exploringjs.com, tons of blog posts, SO, everything I could find -- no resource talks about the details like you have here.  It was only through trial an error I got it working.  Actually this SO post tipped me off as to how it could work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527733/es6-calling-super-doesnt-properly-initialize-parent-class

Comment: The best thing you can do is to check both Babel and Typescript generated code. After wasting some time with junk they put to the output it starts to make perfect sense. If you have good experience with ES5, you will recognize these inheritance recipes, since ES6 classes are just sugar syntax for ES5 counterparts for the most part.